Ubuntu 24.04 on 32" 4K Samsung monitor - extremely large display issue during boot
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 on a 32" Samsung 4K monitor, and I'm experiencing an issue where the display elements are extremely large, but this only happens during the initial boot when I'm prompted to enter my password to decrypt the disk. Once I'm logged in, the display returns to normal. I tried adjusting resolution and scaling settings, but it doesn't seem to affect this particular screen. Has anyone else encountered this problem or has any suggestions on how to fix it?

